# How to store multiple related values in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a set of checkboxes in a page and each checkbox is associated with a textbox.

What I need to do is to disable the textbox if the checkbox is unchecked and put a default value inside it(each textbox has a different default value).

Right now I have written a function which accepts checkboxId, textboxId and the default value which is called onClick of the checkbox.

Is there a way to store this information(checkBoxId,textBoxId,defaultValue) statically(like a map or something) in javascript so that my function does not require any arguments and can be called onLoad of the page?

Comment: Store them using `data-` would be the best way imo.

Comment: In js you can go for `Object()` to store associate data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something I did before:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="sample">
<input data-requires="sample" data-default="Default">

function applyControls(){
    $("input[data-requires]").each(function(){
        var target = $(this);
        $("#" + target.data("requires")).click(function(){
            if(this.checked){
                target.prop("disabled", false);
            }else{
                target.prop("disabled", true).val(target.data("default"));
            }
        });
    });
}
applyControls();
```

<sup>Note: This code is written with jQuery. You can easily convert this to native code by substituting jQuery methods with native methods.</sup>

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/VnHAc/

Now this way you don't have to create any map or Object to store these relations (you don't even need `id`s for individual textboxes!) By using `data-*` attributes, you do not have to modify a "map" every single time you add connections. In fact, this is the preferred way<sup>1</sup> of doing it in HTML5.

<sub><sup>1</sup> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes</sub>